# Magento - Export products (with Dataflow) to CSV with a cronjob

Tags: php, xml, magento, dataflow

I want to export the Magento products every night to a CSV file. The Dataflow in Magento works perfect, but I can't setup a cronjob with that. The CSV lay-out should be the same as the Dataflow export.

Do you have an idea how I can fix that? I googled a lot for this, but it seems that nobody asked this before.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following link can be useful for your needs:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/113901/P30/#t277875

Hope it helps.

Regards,
Alessandro

Comment: I think this will help. Thank you!